# Deploy Ant project into Maven repository

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, ant

I am new using Maven and I need to upload some libraries from an Ant project. To develop this task I have one folder that contains a lot of "pom.xml" files that refers to the jar that I would like to add to my project in Eclipse using Maven, and another xml file that is the Ant project itself.

All ideas are welcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately no good tools exists for Ant to Maven migration. You will need going step by step from module to module do so:

1. Enable maven nature on each project.
2. Resolve maven dependency by hand.
3. Deploy artifact into local or remote repository.

Comment: Thank you so much, I will follow those steps to deploy it manually. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

Pay your attention on version numbers of libraries. Make sure the md5 hash or sha2 hash of library in ant project and the library received in maven after adding dependency is exactly same. Otherwise you will definitely get some non traceable errors if not during testing but after deployment to prod.